# Ubuntu 20.04 Raspberry Pi 4b PXE boot fails after run /init

Tags: boot, raspberrypi, pxe, embedded-system

I have been trying to PXE boot Ubuntu 20.04 server lts for the rpi4 since about a week now, and I am basically stuck at the point where /init is executed and the boot process basically stalls. I can't find any clue as to why it hangs there. It looks as if init doesn't know where the rootfs is, but I could be wrong. The rpi 4b IP can be pinged after the boot process is stalled, but I cant ssh into it. I am wondering if I am stuck into some kind of u-boot stage. Unfortunately the serial console doesn't give out any output past the point where the boot process hangs. I have sort of been following [this guy indications](https://askubuntu.com/a/1273250) but some steps do look truly unclear to me.

**Setup info:**

TFTP + NFS server is 172.12.1.1; RPI 4b static lease IP is 172.12.1.51

**cmdline.txt**

```
net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc init=initrd.img ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=172.12.1.1:/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0,vers=3,proto=tcp rw
```

**config.txt**

```
[pi4]
kernel=uboot_rpi_4.bin
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
arm_64bit=1
device_tree_address=0x03000000
enable_uart=1
uart_2ndstage=1
cmdline=cmdline.txt
include syscfg.txt
include usercfg.txt
kernel=vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi
initramfs initrd.img-5.4.0-1028-raspi followkernel
```

**boot folder files on NFS server**

```
vswitch0:~$ file /var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/*
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/System.map-5.4.0-1028-raspi: regular file, no read permission
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/cmdline.txt:                 ASCII text
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/config-5.4.0-1028-raspi:     Linux make config build file, ASCII text
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/config.txt:                  ASCII text
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/firmware:                    directory
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/initrd.img:                  symbolic link to initrd.img-5.4.0-1028-raspi
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1028-raspi: LZ4 compressed data (v0.1-v0.9)
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/initrd.img.old:              symbolic link to initrd.img-5.4.0-1028-raspi
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/vmlinuz:                     symbolic link to vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi:    Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image, little-endian, 4K pages
/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/vmlinuz.old:                 symbolic link to vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi
vswitch0:~$
```

**fstab**

```
vswitch0:~$ cat /var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/etc/fstab 
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
172.12.1.1:/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0 / nfs defaults,rw,nolock     0       0
172.12.1.1:/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0/boot/firmware /boot/firmware  nfs  defaults,rw,nolock 0   1 
none            /tmp            tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/run        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/lock       tmpfs   defaults        0       0
none            /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults        0       0

vswitch0:~$
```

**Boot logs**

```
 [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
    [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-1028-raspi (buildd@bos02-arm64-034) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 20 11:30:45 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-1028.31-raspi 5.4.78)
    [    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
    [    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT:
    [    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
    [    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x0000000029400000, size 64 MiB
    [    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
    [    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 32 pages/cpu s92120 r8192 d30760 u131072
    [    0.000000] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU0
    [    0.000000] CPU features: detected: EL2 vector hardening
    [    0.000000] CPU features: kernel page table isolation forced ON by KASLR
    [    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Kernel page table isolation (KPTI)
    [    0.000000] ARM_SMCCC_ARCH_WORKAROUND_1 missing from firmware
    [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 2028848
    [    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=0 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=0 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:D5:BA:19 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc init=initrd.img ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=172.12.1.1:/var/exports/nfsboot/kube0,vers=3,proto=tcp rw
    [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
    [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
    [    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
    [    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x37400000-0x3b400000] (64MB)
    [    0.000000] Memory: 7900492K/8245248K available (11772K kernel code, 1240K rwdata, 4248K rodata, 4096K init, 1076K bss, 279220K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved)
    [    0.000000] random: get_random_u64 called from kmem_cache_open+0x3c/0x3e0 with crng_init=0
    [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
    [    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 39051 entries in 153 pages
    [    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
    [    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
    [    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
    [    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
    [    0.000000] GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
    [    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 54.00MHz (phys).
    [    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0xc743ce346, max_idle_ns: 440795203123 ns
    [    0.000005] sched_clock: 56 bits at 54MHz, resolution 18ns, wraps every 4398046511102ns
    [    0.000213] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
    [    0.000648] printk: console [tty1] enabled
    [    0.000713] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 108.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=216000)
    [    0.000748] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
    [    0.000976] LSM: Security Framework initializing
    [    0.001039] Yama: becoming mindful.
    [    0.001142] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
    [    0.001404] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
    [    0.001506] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
    [    0.001594] *** VALIDATE tmpfs ***
    [    0.002245] *** VALIDATE proc ***
    [    0.002806] Disabling memory control group subsystem
    [    0.002895] *** VALIDATE cgroup1 ***
    [    0.002918] *** VALIDATE cgroup2 ***
    [    0.004276] ASID allocator initialised with 32768 entries
    [    0.004472] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
    [    0.006589] EFI services will not be available.
    [    0.007450] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
    [    0.008500] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU1
    [    0.008554] CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000001 [0x410fd083]
    [    0.009599] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU2
    [    0.009637] CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000002 [0x410fd083]
    [    0.010666] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU3
    [    0.010704] CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000003 [0x410fd083]
    [    0.010853] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
    [    0.010941] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated.
    [    0.010962] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
    [    0.010984] CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
    [    0.018538] CPU features: emulated: Privileged Access Never (PAN) using TTBR0_EL1 switching
    [    0.018566] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL2
    [    0.018624] alternatives: patching kernel code
    [    0.020632] devtmpfs: initialized
    [    0.030294] Enabled cp15_barrier support
    [    0.030342] Enabled setend support
    [    0.030840] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
    [    0.030882] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
    [    0.033228] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
    [    0.033879] DMI not present or invalid.
    [    0.034550] NET: Registered protocol family 16
    [    0.037134] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic allocations
    [    0.037168] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
    [    0.037441] audit: type=2000 audit(0.036:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
    [    0.037993] cpuidle: using governor ladder
    [    0.038048] cpuidle: using governor menu
    [    0.038514] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
    [    0.038836] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
    [    0.041646] bcm2835-mbox fe00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
    [    0.052149] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2021-01-08 14:31, variant start
    [    0.056156] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 194a85abd768c7334bbadc3f1911c10a7d18ed14
    [    0.098377] bcm2835-dma fe007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
    [    0.101529] iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
    [    0.102749] SCSI subsystem initialized
    [    0.103208] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.103267] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.103389] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    0.103738] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
    [    0.103759] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
    [    0.103794] PTP clock support registered
    [    0.104111] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
    [    0.105480] NetLabel: Initializing
    [    0.105507] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
    [    0.105525] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
    [    0.105602] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
    [    0.106505] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
    [    0.196506] *** VALIDATE bpf ***
    [    0.196901] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
    [    0.197007] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    0.197152] *** VALIDATE ramfs ***
    [    0.197788] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
    [    0.207747] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
    [    0.207753] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
    [    0.207781] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
    [    0.207801] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
    [    0.207820] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'power_allocator'
    [    0.208360] NET: Registered protocol family 2
    [    0.209118] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
    [    0.209201] TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
    [    0.209562] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
    [    0.210374] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536)
    [    0.210756] UDP hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
    [    0.210865] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
    [    0.211231] NET: Registered protocol family 1
    [    0.211275] NET: Registered protocol family 44
    [    0.211302] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
    [    0.211585] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
    [    0.867507] Freeing initrd memory: 28652K
    [    0.869147] hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_cortex_a72 PMU driver, 7 counters available
    [    0.869361] kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 44bits
    [    0.870258] kvm [1]: vgic interrupt IRQ1
    [    0.870545] kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully
    [    0.872746] Initialise system trusted keyrings
    [    0.872812] Key type blacklist registered
    [    0.873089] workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=21 bucket_order=0
    [    0.879977] zbud: loaded
    [    0.882004] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
    [    0.883077] fuse: init (API version 7.31)
    [    0.883209] *** VALIDATE fuse ***
    [    0.883233] *** VALIDATE fuse ***
    [    0.908071] Key type asymmetric registered
    [    0.908095] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
    [    0.908151] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 242)
    [    0.908489] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
    [    0.912765] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
    [    0.912803] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   No bus range found for /scb/pcie@7d500000, using [bus 00-ff]
    [    0.912872] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:      MEM 0x0600000000..0x0603ffffff -> 0x00f8000000
    [    0.912938] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   IB MEM 0x0000000000..0x00bfffffff -> 0x0400000000
    [    0.976606] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5 GT/s x1 (SSC)
    [    0.976896] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
    [    0.976925] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
    [    0.976952] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x603ffffff] (bus address [0xf8000000-0xfbffffff])
    [    0.977015] pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
    [    0.977224] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
    [    0.980896] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
    [    0.981040] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
    [    0.981401] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
    [    0.985021] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 14: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
    [    0.985055] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
    [    0.985100] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
    [    0.985128] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
    [    0.985393] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    0.985592] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 41
    [    0.985958] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 41
    [    0.986218] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    1.030842] pci 0000:01:00.0: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x658 took 43570 usecs
    [    1.032102] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Unable to determine number of FBs. Disabling driver.
    [    1.032142] bcm2708_fb: probe of soc:fb failed with error -2
    [    1.095419] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
    [    1.097841] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
    [    1.098278] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
    [    1.099118] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe200000
    [    1.099470] cacheinfo: Unable to detect cache hierarchy for CPU 0
    [    1.461968] loop: module loaded
    [    1.464644] spi-bcm2835 fe204000.spi: could not get clk: -517
    [    1.466354] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
    [    1.466401] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
    [    1.467077] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet clock
    [    1.467108] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
    [    1.467136] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet-wol clock
    [    1.467163] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet-eee clock
    [    1.467197] bcmgenet: Skipping UMAC reset
    [    1.478543] libphy: bcmgenet MII bus: probed
    [    1.534600] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
    [    1.535410] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
    [    1.535701] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
    [    1.535771] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
    [    1.535813] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
    [    1.535850] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
    [    1.535914] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
    [    1.535943] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
    [    1.536005] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
    [    1.536436] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
    [    1.536476] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
    [    1.537240] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000003000000890
    [    1.538384] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
    [    1.538416] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    1.538442] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [    1.538464] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-1028-raspi xhci-hcd
    [    1.538523] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
    [    1.539099] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
    [    1.539195] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
    [    1.539776] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
    [    1.539808] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
    [    1.539844] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
    [    1.540214] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.04
    [    1.540243] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    1.540269] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [    1.540289] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-1028-raspi xhci-hcd
    [    1.540311] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
    [    1.540861] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
    [    1.540928] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
    [    1.541796] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
    [    1.542651] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
    [    1.543090] i2c /dev entries driver
    [    1.545970] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
    [    1.546187] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
    [    1.546529] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.41.0-ioctl (2019-09-16) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
    [    1.550213] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
    [    1.550224] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
    [    1.550450] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
    [    1.550636] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
    [    1.552765] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
    [    1.552906] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
    [    1.553608] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (____ptrval____)
    [    1.555818] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
    [    1.556263] NET: Registered protocol family 10
    [    1.573345] Segment Routing with IPv6
    [    1.573412] NET: Registered protocol family 17
    [    1.573514] Key type dns_resolver registered
    [    1.573876] registered taskstats version 1
    [    1.573916] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
    [    1.575359] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 09ad5a0751a3e9ca1eb19d9275b4d0b41e50fa66'
    [    1.575567] Key type ._fscrypt registered
    [    1.575576] Key type .fscrypt registered
    [    1.592147] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
    [    1.610393] Key type big_key registered
    [    1.633115] Key type encrypted registered
    [    1.633138] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
    [    1.633161] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
    [    1.633184] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
    [    1.633208] ima: No architecture policies found
    [    1.633241] evm: Initialising EVM extended attributes:
    [    1.633249] evm: security.selinux
    [    1.633255] evm: security.SMACK64
    [    1.633262] evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
    [    1.633268] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
    [    1.633274] evm: security.SMACK64MMAP
    [    1.633281] evm: security.apparmor
    [    1.633287] evm: security.ima
    [    1.633293] evm: security.capability
    [    1.633300] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
    [    1.637108] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
    [    1.637177] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 14, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
    [    1.641984] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
    [    1.642024] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 16, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
    [    1.906507] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
    [    1.906890] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
    [    2.118790] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
    [    2.123304] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
    [    2.126915] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
    [    2.126919] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
    [    2.153363] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
    [    2.164542] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
    [    2.174900] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
    [    3.138686] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
    [    3.188667] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
    [    3.195751] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
    [    3.202835] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
    [    3.211117] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
    [    3.216698] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.emmc2 [fe340000.emmc2] using ADMA
    [    3.225153] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
    [    3.225754] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
    [    3.230564] of_cfs_init
    [    3.238396] of_cfs_init: OK
    [    3.241585] bcmgenet: Skipping UMAC reset
    [    3.247330] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII
    [    3.254960] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
    [    3.257799] random: fast init done
    [    3.297954] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
    [   18.622593] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
    [   18.631091] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
    [   18.646500] Sending DHCP requests ., OK
    [   18.666412] IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 172.12.1.1, my address is 172.12.1.51
    [   18.674018] IP-Config: Complete:
    [   18.677300]      device=eth0, hwaddr=dc:a6:32:d5:ba:19, ipaddr=172.12.1.51, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=172.12.1.1
    [   18.687364]      host=kube0, domain=node1.eth1.lan, nis-domain=(none)
    [   18.693902]      bootserver=0.0.0.0, rootserver=0.0.0.0, rootpath=
    [   18.693904]      nameserver0=172.12.0.1, nameserver1=172.12.1.1
    [   18.711592] Freeing unused kernel memory: 4096K
    [   18.750294] Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found
    [   18.756067] Run /init as init process
    [   18.813257] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
    [   18.819196] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
    [   18.823155] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
    [   19.354399] usb_phy_generic phy: phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
    [   21.594496] raid6: neonx8   gen()  3188 MB/s
    [   21.646496] raid6: neonx8   xor()  2867 MB/s
    [   21.698511] raid6: neonx4   gen()  2519 MB/s
    [   21.750498] raid6: neonx4   xor()  2326 MB/s
    [   21.802494] raid6: neonx2   gen()  2231 MB/s
    [   21.854491] raid6: neonx2   xor()  2282 MB/s
    [   21.906500] raid6: neonx1   gen()  1921 MB/s
    [   21.958499] raid6: neonx1   xor()  1739 MB/s
    [   22.010496] raid6: int64x8  gen()  1660 MB/s
    [   22.062491] raid6: int64x8  xor()  1230 MB/s
    [   22.114523] raid6: int64x4  gen()  1438 MB/s
    [   22.166501] raid6: int64x4  xor()  1121 MB/s
    [   22.218538] raid6: int64x2  gen()  1132 MB/s
    [   22.270494] raid6: int64x2  xor()   996 MB/s
    [   22.322523] raid6: int64x1  gen()   970 MB/s
    [   22.374511] raid6: int64x1  xor()   684 MB/s
    [   22.378844] raid6: using algorithm neonx8 gen() 3188 MB/s
    [   22.384323] raid6: .... xor() 2867 MB/s, rmw enabled
    [   22.389362] raid6: using neon recovery algorithm
    [   22.397745] xor: measuring software checksum speed
    [   22.442503]    8regs     :  5940.000 MB/sec
    [   22.486487]    32regs    :  6782.000 MB/sec
    [   22.530486]    arm64_neon:  6118.000 MB/sec
    [   22.534731] xor: using function: 32regs (6782.000 MB/sec)
    [   22.542067] async_tx: api initialized (async)
    [  209.086534] random: crng init done
    [  209.089984] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
```

Full boot logs can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/9K2XPq6A). Thanks