# Orange PI 5 Diskless cluster

Tags: raspberrypi, cluster

I previously asked and answered a question about how to boot a Rpi4b completely diskless and Id like to achieve the same result with an Orange Pi.

[Raspberry Pi - Diskless Cluster using Ubuntu 20.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273084/raspberry-pi-diskless-cluster-using-ubuntu-20-04-1)

Currently Im unable to install an OS since the OPi keeps rebooting so it looks like I'll need to:

- firmware update
- clear the emmc
- attempt a normal os install
- install a bootloader into the emmc
- investigate pxe booting and see if we can do that with an empty mmc just using dhcp.